# What do I receive when I get a drop for a character whose constellation is already complete?

Tags: genshin-impact

On the last couple 10 Wishes I have pulled, I have obtained Noelle on every single pull, so I have received 5 of Noelle's Stella Fortuna. Once I have Noelle's constellation complete, what do I get the next time the character drops on a wish?

Comment: Disappointment?

Comment: @pinckerman After getting Noelle on every single 10 pull? Yeah

Comment: LOL no, that was meant to answer your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a duplicate 4 star character on whom you already got c6, you get 5 masterless starglitter. For a duplicate 5 star character on whom you got c6, you get 25 masterless starglitter ... and disappointment.

| wished item | Additional reward |
| --- | --- |
| New Character | None |
| Duplicate 5★ Character | 10 Masterless Starglitter and 1 Stella Fortuna for that character |
| Duplicate 5★ Character (Constellations Maxed) | 25 Masterless Starglitter |
| Duplicate 4★ Character | 2 Masterless Starglitter and 1 Stella Fortuna for that character |
| Duplicate 4★ Character (Constellations Maxed) | 5 Masterless Starglitter |
| 5★ Weapon | 10 Masterless Starglitter |
| 4★ Weapon | 2 Masterless Starglitter |
| 3★ Weapon | 15 Masterless Stardust |

Source: [Genshin Impact Wiki](https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Wishes)